# VPN-Client on virtual interface

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

We have the following two interfaces (2nd is a virtual one) on a ubuntu machine:

```
eth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr abc
         inet addr:x.x.x.110  Bcast:x.x.x.127  Mask:255.255.255.224
eth0:1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr (also) abc/same like above
         inet addr:x.x.x.111  Bcast:x.x.x.127  Mask:255.255.255.224
```

Both use the same gateway.

What we would like to do is to route all traffic of eth0:1 through a VPN, but leaving eth0 untouched. Otherwise the server would become unreachable for us. We can connect to the VPN via PPTP, IPSec or a openvpn config. We tried using a openvpn client but it always sets up the vpn for both although we trief to bind it to the ip-address off eth0:1 using `local`-parameter in the config.

How to configure it correct? Is it actually possible?